# sqlkata issue when using OrderByRaw

Tags: c#, postgresql, sqlkata

Hi I have found a quite strange error, when using OrderByRaw method of SqlKata.

```
var query = new Query("SoftwareVersions").OrderByRaw("string_to_array([version], '.')::int[] DESC")
```

Also tested it here https://sqlkata.com/playground/pgsql same error.

the problem is with the int square brackets, they are being converted as "column" with nothing in or simply 2 quotes, here is the result that is completely identical with that produced by SqlKata in runtime:

```
SELECT * FROM "SoftwareVersions" ORDER BY string_to_array("version", '.') :: int "" DESC
```

Note: here you can see after the int cast we have 2 quotes.

My question is how to avoid this unexpected behavior using SQLKata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default SqlKata swap the `[]` to the corresponding delimiters for each compiler, hence this is why you are getting the double quotes `"`, in MySql you may get the backtick and so on.

To avoid this, simply escape them with a backslash.

```cs
.OrderByRaw(@"string_to_array([version], '.')::int\[\] DESC")
```

Check https://sqlkata.com/playground/pgsql?code=var%20query%20%3D%20new%20Query(%22SoftwareVersions%22).OrderByRaw(%40%22string_to_array(%5Bversion%5D%2C%20'.')%3A%3Aint%5C%5B%5C%5D%20DESC%22

Comment: which "identifiers" are you talking about? -thanks, TJ –

Comment: like the `\`` for MySql, and `"` for Postgres

Comment: But aren't they(' or ") called string terminators or delimiters, rather than identifiers., like a table name or a column name. So, "By default SqlKata swaps the raw sql delimiters to the corresponding oracle/MySql delimiters for the identifiers "

Comment: You are totally right, updated the answer